# Sencha-touch with custum design

Tags: sencha-touch

I am working on sencha touch mobile app. I am weak in css and html5. I am founding if a designer make same design using css and html5. How can i use it on sencha touch?Is that possible in sencha touch to work with UI/UX developer.

Please suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Theming is done in Sencha Touch with SASS.

Start by reading 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/guide/theming

Good luck!

Comment: Adding to the above. Here is a link that gets you started on theming Sencha Touch app using SASS. 
http://www.uvd.co.uk/blog/theming-sencha-touch-with-sass/